# Product Tags feature is not included in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, seo, product-page, tags, product-tag

First, I'm confused whether this question will fit the requirements of a question expected on this site, if that's the case, please indicate that.

Just installed a fresh version of Magento 2 to get the feel of the new system. When going through modules, I noticed that the Product Tags feature is not there. Also, couldn't find any admin page for the same. Looked around the web but couldn't find any relevant information on that.

Has Magento dropped that feature in the new release, if yes, does anyone know why? That happened to be one of some awesome features of Magento right out-of-the-box.

Comment: Anyone found any alternative or the extension.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There was a survey conducted at one point on twitter (and maybe other channels) By Elena Leonova asking the community if they use certain modules from Magento 1.
After this survey, the decision was taken to not port the tags and polls modules to Magento 2 because there was not much use of them.
But I'm almost sure someone from the community will implement them for Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ***Magento dropped this feature from  Magento 2***. There are ***no any core module is exist in Magento2.***

It indicates that this feature is deprecated at **Magento 2**

May  be **`#benmarks & @Alankent`**, will tell us why this ***feature had removed from Magento  2***

Comment: So How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You have to build custom module/extension yourself

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not used by stores anymore, it is not useful for customer navigation. Years ago, it had some SEO value but does not have it anymore, together with HTML site maps. It was removed so there is less code to maintain.

As Marius mentioned, if there is a need, there will be a community module to do that.

I'm curious why you say it was awesome - I personally haven't seen any interesting, modern store use it.

Comment: As it is by default - not so useful it's true. But this is was good base for true powerful SEO tweaking like http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/seo-product-tag-urls.html and http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-product-tagging.html Tags become awesome cross-linking feature which is still have very high SEO value. For sure community will handle it, we already start some implementation.

Comment: @Piotr, Tags allow customers to engage with the store in their own way. They get to keep things the way they wanted. I'm not sure how you concluded it was not good for SEO, as a proper implementation has helped many stores gain customer trust, which ultimately resulted into better site appearance in search results.

Comment: Jumping in a year late - we do not use tags for SEO directly but we use tag as a great way to relate blog, content and products. Tags for user friendly navigation still have value, allowing to highlight particular aspects of products and cross link, without creating an attribute each time
- show related products on content - integrate with external cms/blog which use tags - build a landing page on any theme (pull posts, products with tag, add intro and image). - enrich product page pulling useful articles via tags ( "how to pick the right ..." advice). better than 12 modules!