# Poll option in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2. I need to include a poll functionality in Magento 2. Poll option was directly available in Magento 1. 
This is the link(Magento 1)-"http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/polls.html"

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Polls and Product tags features have been removed from Magento CE 2.0 as said by @Marius;

> There was a survey conducted at one point on twitter (and maybe other 
>   channels) By Elena Leonova asking the community if they use certain
>   modules  from Magento 1. After this survey, the decision was taken to
>   not port the tags  and polls modules to Magento 2 because there was
>   not much use of them. But I'm  almost sure someone from the community
>   will implement them for Magento 2.

Reference: [Product Tags feature is not included in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86259/product-tags-feature-is-not-included-in-magento-2)