# Magento 2 - How do I create a voting poll?

Tags: magento2, module, local

I would like to create a voting poll inside one of my pages. I've researched online and found a tutorial for Magento 1 and I was wondering if there was a similar way to achieve this in Magento 2.

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/polls.html

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polls and Product tags features have been removed from Magento CE 2.0 as said by @Marius;

> There was a survey conducted at one point on twitter (and maybe other
>   channels) By Elena Leonova asking the community if they use certain
>   modules from Magento 1. After this survey, the decision was taken to
>   not port the tags and polls modules to Magento 2 because there was not
>   much use of them. But I'm almost sure someone from the community will
>   implement them for Magento 2.

Reference - [Product Tags feature is not included in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86259/product-tags-feature-is-not-included-in-magento-2)

You'll have to find a third party solution or develop a custom solution yourself